# Blocks only visible to Admin, despite clear permissions

Tags: 7, views, blocks, users

This problem concerns two related content types: Vendors and Resources (which are products sold by the Vendors). I have set up a Views block, "Resources by vendor", to display on all Vendor pages.

It uses a contextual filter with a relationship to the Resource NID, and works perfectly when logged in: when you go to a Vendor page, you see the Vendor's information (from the node), along with a list of Resources offered by that Vendor (from the block).

However, when I log out, that block is not visible.

As far as I can tell, I have all the appropriate permissions set correctly:

- On the Block configuration: Roles - not restricted.
  - Also tried checking off all roles; still no change.
- On the View: Access - None.
  - Also tried Permission: View published content, and Role: (all roles checked) with no effect.
- In Permissions, all roles are allowed to view published content; no restrictions on viewing the Resource or Vendor content types

Can anyone think of what I might be missing?

Comment: Are you using the field permissions module? Roles must be able to view that field I think.